# How to create shortcut for Control Tab with Autohotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

What would be the script in Autohotkey in order to create a keyboard shortcut that presses Control plus Tab in order to move along tabs of a dialog?

Answer (score 2):

```
F1:: Send, ^{Tab}
```

See https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm
how to send simulated keystrokes and mouse clicks to the active window.